Edge table on cytoscape won't show gene name on the shared name pp interaction column
Could you help me solve this problem?
So, basically both shared name and name column on this edge table not showing the gene name. It just show like this picture.
How can I change the name in the name table into gene name based on query term?


Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are expecting to see. Is this about seeing the names of the nodes in the network? Or about the table itself which is all you have shown us? Can you give us the actual data in text form (only a few lines, not the whole thing) so we can try to reproduce it? I don't see any gene names there, you seem to have protein names, I guess that's what you mean?

You need to use the mapSourceAndTarget tool (the little table icon in the header of the edge table) and map to display name.
